# What is the best way to model sequence paths in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say my graph is a series of steps, which connect to one another in a procedure.   Is there a best/recommended way to model this in a graph?

I can think of two different approaches:

Number one:

```
CREATE [s1:Step]-[r1:step { procedure: "Foo" }]->[s2:Step]
```

In this method, I need to examine properties of the `step` relationship to reconstitute an entire procedure.  Just follow all the relationships labeled procedure: Foo.

Number two:

```
CREATE (p:Procedure {name: "Foo"}), 
       (s1:Step), (s2:Step), 
       p-[:step { sequence: 0 }]->s1, 
       p-[:step { sequence: 1 }]->s2;
```

This creates an actual first-class procedure "node" but buys me the problem of having to specify the sequence number so I know which order the steps should be in.

This problem must have been solved a dozen times before though.  Is there a better/best pattern for modeling this as a graph?

Answer (score 2):

The following approach might be suitable for your needs. It creates a chain of Step nodes rooted at a Procedure node.

The Procedure node also has a LAST_STEP relationship to point to the currently last Step node, in an attempt to enable more performant appending of new Step nodes. But there might be a more efficient way to handle this.

A possible drawback to this approach is that you cannot parametrize the number of steps in #4.

1. To initiate the chain of steps for a procedure, starting with the
   first step:

   > ```
   > CREATE (p:Procedure {name: "Foo"})-[:LAST_STEP]->(s:Step {...}), (p)-[:NEXT_STEP]->(s);
   > ```
2. To add a step to the end of a chain:

   > ```
   > MATCH (p:Procedure {name: "Foo"})-[ls:LAST_STEP]->(s)
   > DELETE ls
   > CREATE (p)-[:LAST_STEP]->(s1:Step {...})
   > CREATE (s)-[:NEXT_STEP]->(s1);
   > ```
3. To get the 1st step for a chain (or null if there are no steps):

   > ```
   > MATCH (p:Procedure {name: "Foo"})-[:NEXT_STEP]->(s)
   > RETURN s;
   > ```
4. To get the 3rd step for a chain, or null if there are fewer than 3 steps (you can replace `3` with any number):

   > ```
   > MATCH (p:Procedure {name: "Foo"})-[:NEXT_STEP*3]->(s)
   > RETURN s;
   > ```
5. To get the step after step `s` (assuming we already have `s` somehow):

   > ```
   > ...
   > MATCH (s)-[:NEXT_STEP]->(s1)
   > RETURN s1;
   > ```
6. To get all the steps in a chain, in order:

   > ```
   > MATCH (p:Procedure {name: "Foo"})-[ns:NEXT_STEP*]->(s)
   > RETURN s ORDER BY length(ns);
   > ```

Answer (score 1):

i think index searching is not a good idea
its better to use label scanning
we can`t use several labels on relations and have 64k relation type limits
if your need dont exceed this limitations u can use something like this

```
a-[:STEP_FOO]-b-[STEP_BAR]-c
```